# Check if the program is idle or running for some time in Java

Tags: java

I wanted to create a desktop project. In that If the program is not used for some minutes it should automatically display the login screen. I understand that it can be easily done using http servlet session in web apps (as told by some friends).  But how it is possible in javafx or desktop apps. Can anyone tell me... Please

Comment: Attach an observer to the main event dispatching queue, monitor the events going through it - make determinations about weather the event is a "user input" event or not

Comment: Could you please make it clear with codes..

Comment: I don't know, can you do an internet search? Sorry if that's a little unfriendly, but we're not a code making machine and my understanding of the event dispatching algorithm in JavaFX is limited - I just wanted to try and seed the idea to provide you with a better idea of what to search for

Comment: Thanks for replying and giving me an idea

Comment: Please review the documentation on how to ask effective questions. This is not a code writing service

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so based on [Working with Event Filters](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm), you could do something like...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField btn = new TextField();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new KeyHandler());       
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new KeyHandler());      
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new KeyHandler());     
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MouseHandler());     
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new MouseHandler());     
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new MouseHandler());     
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new MouseHandler());      
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, new MouseHandler());       
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new MouseHandler());     
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new MouseHandler());        

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    protected class KeyHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Key Event");
        }

    }

    protected class MouseHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Mouse Event");
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Now, all this really does is provides you with information about when an event occurred. You'd need to setup some kind of "timeout", maybe something like [JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task).

My personal idea wold be to have a `Timeline` running on a short period (Maybe 1-5 seconds) and checking how long the last input was, if it exceeds the "time out" period, you can switch to the login view.  This way, you don't need to keep stoping and starting the `Timeline`.

For this I'd be making use of the new date/time API introduced in Java 8. See [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) for more details

## PS...

I also found that ...

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new KeyHandler());
scene.setOnKeyReleased(new KeyHandler());
scene.setOnKeyTyped(new KeyHandler());

primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

could also work.

I've not tested it, but [`Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) also has `addEventFilter` and `addEventHandler`, which might be suitable for establishing the same concept from above to the `Stage` instead of the `Scene`.